# What is an usage of these things in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, visibility, access-modifiers

I've been learning Kotlin and I'm currently faced with two problems.

> What's the usage of private constructors?
>   What's the usage of private
>   parameters in constructors?

1. We cannot even create an instance of a class that has a private constructor
2. Private parameters in constructors...

Thus, they will be visible only in that class? But, they do it and without the `private` modifier in constructor.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Private constructors**

It's similar to `java`. You can forbid creation of class instances if a class has only private constructors. Or you can allow to this class to be responsible of creation of its instances (like it is done in the Singleton pattern).

```
class Singleton private constructor(val name: String) {
    companion object {
        fun getInstance(): Singleton {
            return Singleton()   // Simplified
        }
    }
}
```

**Constructor private parameters**

If a constructor of a class `C` has a `val s: String` parameter it becomes an instance public property property and can be accessed like `C.s`. If we will declare such parameters as a `private` it will become an instance private property.

```
class Holder(private val pri: String, val pub: String) {
}

val holder = Holder("private", "public")
holder.pub    // contains "public"
holder.pri    // not accessible
```

Answer (score 1):

This is same as Java private constructor, you can instantiate the class by using companion object methods.

```
class Foo private constructor(val someData: Data) {
    companion object {
        fun constructorA(): Foo {
            // do stuff

            return Foo(someData)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```